# How to have an ImageButton behaving like a ViewGroup?

Tags: android, button, textview, imageview

I want to have an image and over an image i want to put a shorter semi transparent view and put a textview inside of that view and finally i want all of these clickable which shows basic clicking effect like on buttons.

I can't use

```
<Button>
   <ImageView>
      <TextView/>
   </ImageView>
</Button>
```

I can create a LinearLayout with Clickable=true. But how can i imitate the visual press effect which exists on buttons?

**UPDATE:** I added an image which shows how i want it to be seen. Think this something like an ImageButton (it should have on-press effect)

[image]

**UPDATE-2:** I added another image which shows the pressed effect. (Similar to Play Store app).
[image]

Comment: Would be helpful if you could draw and show us what you want. May be it won't have to be that complicated as it sounds.

Comment: Do you need any of the ImageView scaling options or can you do with a stretched out image?

Comment: I think you can style most layout/views with shapes/styles.

Comment: i have uploaded an image.

Comment: @DeeV I don't want to generate (text+image combined) rendered bitmap :|

Comment: You could just make a custom component and make the whole component clickable. ImageButtons are just imageviews pretty much, you can't change that. And if you want to include layout, just make the whole view clickable and compose it with the pieces you do know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a ViewGroup (e.g. LinearLayout/RelativeLayout/etc) that contains the image and text, etc.

Make this ViewGroup clickable (e.g. by assigning it an OnClicListener).

Assign a **background** drawable to this ViewGroup.

Make sure that this background drawable is a state-list drawable:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Assign the appropriate drawable to the various states (most importantly state_pressed, but you may want to handle other states as well).

When the user presses the button, the appropriate drawable will be shown and will appear as if the ViewGroup is a button (something that can be pressed).

**Update after OP showing new image for pressed state:**

Add a View that is on top of your image/text/etc, with a background that has a StateListDrawable:

```
<RelativeLayout >
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/somerealpngfile"
        ... 
    />
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ... 
    />
    <View 
        android:id+"@+id/clickable_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/selectable_background"
        android:clickable="true"

        ... 
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**res/drawable/selectable_background.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/grid_state_pressed"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/grid_state_focused"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

res/values/colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  ...
  <color name="grid_state_pressed">#BB7dbcd3</color>
  <color name="grid_state_focused">#777dbcd3</color>
  ...
</resources>
```

where colors `grid_state_pressed` and `grid_state_focused` are semi transparent (i.e. their alpha is less than 255).

When the user clicks your 'button' the View with `R.id.clickable_view` will handle the onClick and will change its background color, causing the image and text shine through in a semi transparent way.

Comment: Thanks. I need a dynamic press-effect instead of image_pressed.png

Comment: You could still do that. Instead of specifying a android:drawable in each <item/>, you could add children to <item> describing a layer-list drawable (<layer-list ..>).

Comment: I tried this, but transparency does not work: `<item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <color android:color="#080000ff"/>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/somerealpngfile"></bitmap>
    </item>`

Comment: I tried this and it worked! Can i bind "somerealpngfile" to some variable so i can reuse this xml on many similar "button"s.?    `<item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
         <item>
          <bitmap android:src="@drawable/realpngfile"></bitmap>
         </item>
         <item>
          <color android:color="#bb0000ff"/>
         </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>`

Comment: You can put the <layer-list ...> ... </layer-list> in a separate XML file as a drawable-xml and refer to it by using the <item android:drawable="..."/>.

Comment: Well.. i tried it more and i saw that it's not working like how i want, <bitmap> does not obey to it's parent width and height. So eventhough i set it's <selector> to my clickable View, view's layout_width and layout_height, it doesn't affect the bitmap's width and height.

Comment: Don't add the image to the selectable_background.xml. Instead, like in my initial example, put the image in an ImageView, where you can use width/height and scaletype to make sure the image is shown OK. Have the selectable_background.xml show only semi-transparent colors that will allow the ImageView and TextView to shine through partially.

Comment: I updated my answer with additional/modified xml. Take a look and see it that helps.

Comment: That worked! Thank you, i have chosen your answer as this post has the most detail. Now i'll try to find a good way to make this a component for me, so i can reuse it quickly by just providing, onclick action + background image + text

Comment: No problem! :)    
That's a good idea if you have many of these buttons. I suggest subclassing the RelativeLayout as a custom view, that will load the xml containing the Image, TextView and View with the appropriate background etc. You can make these configurable by creating custom attributes on that custom view.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Layout of your choice to create the effect you want and set the style `@android:style/Widget.Button` on the Layout.

Also, you may need to call `setWillNotDraw(false)` on the layout.

Comment: This was almost there, but i get the highlight only on the border.

Answer (score 1):

But how can I imitate the visual press effect which exists on buttons?

If I'm not mistaken, you can in LinearLayout added android:background="@drawable/some_click"

```
some_click.xml
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
android:state_pressed="true" 
android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
<item
android:state_focused="true" 
android:drawable="@drawable/focused" /> <!-- focused -->
<item
android:drawable="@drawable/default" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't want to change the image but only affect it. Like showing a semi-transparent highlight rectangle all over it when pressed (like Goole Play Store app)